# Select option removal function

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

The following function is supposed to remove a selected value from the selectbox,
and update a hidden field with all values.

I have two problems with it:
Lets say I have the following options in the selectbox : `1071,1000,1052`
After removing the first option (1071), the hidden field is getting a value of `1052,1000,1000`,

if I remove the second option `(1000)` the hidden field is `1052,1052,1071`
if I remove the third one `(1052)`, I get an `options[...].value is null or not an object`

Can someone plz help me fix this ?

```
function removeOptions() {
    var selectbox = document.getElementById('zipcodes');
    var zipcodes = document.getElementById('zip');
    var tmpArray = [];
    var i;
    for (i = selectbox.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (selectbox.options[i].selected){
            selectbox.remove(i);
        }
        tmpArray.push(selectbox.options[i].value);
    }
    zipcodes.value = tmpArray.join(',');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't need the selected value in hidden value, place the portion to push in tmpArray in else part

```
    if (selectbox.options[i].selected){
                selectbox.remove(i);
    }else{
            tmpArray.push(selectbox.options[i].value);
    }
```

Comment: @Raphael You said you want to update the hidden field with *all* values!?